# ListView - show top-most item in other color

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing an Android application which is controlled by a RCU, instead of by touch events/fingers. This RCU has an UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT and OK key (simplified). This means that the OK button is processed on the currently highlighted graphical object. Just think about an interface of an old DVD player, for example.

I am trying to adapt the ListView for this purpose. Say I want to present a vertical list of 5 options:

- Yes              (red)
- Maybe            (white)
- Certainly        (white)
- Possibly         (white)
- Never            (white)

Initially, the first option, Yes, should be in some color (the highlight/focus color), whereas the other 4 options are in another color (default color).

When the user presses UP, Maybe is translated to the top and is displayed in the highlight/focus color; Yes is added on the bottom of the list, and is displayed in the default color:

- Maybe            (red)
- Certainly        (white)
- Possibly         (white)
- Never            (white)
- Yes              (white)

The possible options are provided to the ListView via an ArrayAdapter:

```
    public class DetailOptionsItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public DetailOptionsItemAdapter(Context context, String[] options) {
            super(context, R.layout.options, options);
        }
    }
```

In constructor of class which derives ListView:

```
    setAdapter(new DetailOptionsItemAdapter(getContext(), new String[]{"Yes", ...})));
```

My layout (R.layout.options) is defined as following:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/red"
    android:includeFontPadding="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

When UP or DOWN is received, I translate the requested index to the top:

```
    smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(... the index ..., 0);
```

This works. So far, everything is displayed in white, the default color.

Now I need to plug in that the first item is always red. I tried getting the view at the old position and giving it a while color, and getting the view at the new position and giving it a red color, but without succes.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: you should select an answer if someone provided one that fixed your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am never a huge fan of setting text colors in code, but couldn't you just override the getView() method in the adapter and then depending on the item's position in the list, you can set the text color on it?

ie:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final TextView v =  (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        if (0 == position) {
            v.setTextColor(blah);
        } etc..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had made small demo for implementing ListView's list selector property through pragmatically.

you need to create Custom adapter and inside getView() method just check condition for selected items position and apply color to it.

```
  class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<Setter> setter = new ArrayList<Setter>();
        private int pos;

        public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Setter> list) {
            setter  = list;
            this.context = context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return setter.size() != 0 ? setter.size() : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return setter.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }        

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {                                  
            Holder holder;
            if (convertView == null){
                holder = new Holder();
                convertView =   View.inflate(context, R.layout.item, null);
                holder.txtID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                holder.txtName  =   (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            }          

            if ( pos == position ) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            }else{
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);                
            }           

            holder.txtID.setText(setter.get(position).getId());
            holder.txtName.setText(setter.get(position).getName());            

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {             
                    pos = position;                     
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                 }
            });           
            return convertView;
        }      

    static class Holder{
        TextView txtID;
        TextView txtName;
    }
}
```